# Можно ли заставить NodeJS работать без use strict для конструкций типа class?

Tags: node.js

Если да - то как? А если нет, можно ли как-то объявить use strict в одном месте, а не в каждом скрипте писать (в т.ч. так чтоб не использовать какие-либо require)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"use strict"` можно объявить на уровне функции, не только глобально:

```
var logger = function() {
    "use strict";
     console.log(this);
};
```

В таком случае он будет работать только в области видимости этой фукнции и нигде больше.

Чтоб на весь проект сделать, можно интерпретатору об этом сказать. Когда будете запускать проект, добавьте  `--use_strict`

```
node --use_strict
```

Comment: Так, как сделать так чтобы объявить его только в одном месте и это было применимо ко всему проекту?

Comment: @sanu0074 запускать скрипт как с `node --use_strict`